# Android Cardboard with camera

Tags: android, android-camera, google-cardboard

I'm trying to build a simple app for Android that uses the Cardboard view with the device camera. The Google Cardboard tutorial shows only how to build a cube in a 3D environment but I need to see the real world.
How can I achieve that?